getting error "Cannot locate tasks that match ':app:generateBenchmarkReleaseBaselineProfile'" error when running baseline profiler
After creating a new BaselineProfile module, I tried to execute the task:

and I'm getting the following error:
Cannot locate tasks that match ':app:generateBenchmarkReleaseBaselineProfile' as task 'generateBenchmarkReleaseBaselineProfile' not found in project ':app'.
I'm not seeing any configuration instructions for this in the online docs for baseline profiles. Any clues?

The error is because you are using benchmarkRelease build variant. Instead, just use release build variant and try again

But, shouldn't we use a non-minified/non-obfuscated build for generating baseline profiles? or are you recommending that we modify our release configs?

On the contrary. We generate baseline profiles because we are interested in improving the performance of our application in stores, that is, the buildType of type Release. In fact, it is recommended that it is only generated for that specific build so as not to further delay the compilation time of Debug or any other that is not really the final product.
I recommend modifying your app gradle to only generate baseline profiles exclusively for the Release buildType.

Oh alright, thanks!

@Calixto Works. Upvoted & Thank you.
